# Why is my sitemap file considered empty?

Tags: xml, web, seo, sitemap, robots.txt

I have a robots.txt file in the root of my site which has this one line in it:

```
Sitemap: http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/sitemap.xml
```

The sitemap.xml is also in the root of the site, and contains this text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.awardwinnersonly.com</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-09-16</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/getHugos.cshtml</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-09-16</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>.7</priority>
    <loc>http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/Content/pulitzers2.json</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-09-16</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>.7</priority>
    . . .
      <loc>http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/Content/goldenglobes.json</loc>
      <lastmod>2013-09-16</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>.7</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Yet, after [re]publishing my site, and trying to navigate to http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/sitemap.xml, I get:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

(nothing is shown below that - it is more-or-less a "white screen of death.")

What is wrong with either my xml file, robots file, or how I'm going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like  a stray `-` got into your file.

```
$ curl -v http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/sitemap.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Comment: Dash it all! I wondered if that dash was a problem, but that was there in the URL I copied it from. It now works (pretty much - now I get this as a "banner": This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: I bet your browser tried to render the XML with +/- collapse buttons rather than just showing you the raw XML. I'm able to see it now after I clear my cache.